# Insert string or line after last instance of a specific search variable, in a loop

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm wondering if someone could help me with a specific coding question. I have a DNA sequencing file that reads something like this (as an example):

```
Plate1A1_R1_AGTAGTACGACTAGCATCAGCATACGATCAGCATCAGCATCAG 
Plate1A1_R1_GTAGATCGATGCATGCATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAA 
Plate1A1_R1_AGCTAGCATCGATCGATGCTAGCATGCATCGATCGATGCATGC 
Plate1A1_R2_AGCATCGATGCAGCATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCAGCTAGTCT 
Plate1A1_R2_AGCATGCATCGATCGTAGCTAGCAGCGAGCGGCATCGATCGAT 
Plate1A2_R1_CAGCTAGATGCATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATGCTAGCTTAC 
Plate1A2_R1_CAGTAGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATCGATGCTAGCTAGC 
Plate1A2_R1_ACAACGTAGCTAGCTAGCTACTACTAGTCATCATCGATGCTAG 
Plate1A2_R1_CAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGGCTACATCGATCGTAGCTAGTCGA 
Plate1A2_R1_CAGTCAGCATGCTATCGATCGTAGCTAGTCATCGATGTAGTGA
... etc.
```

You can see that there are lines that belong to the same similar starting pattern (here: Plate1A1_R1, Plate1A1_R2, Plate1A2_R1). I'd like to place a blank line after each grouping, e.g.:

```
Plate1A1_R1_AGTAGTACGACTAGCATCAGCATACGATCAGCATCAGCATCAG 
Plate1A1_R1_GTAGATCGATGCATGCATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAA 
Plate1A1_R1_AGCTAGCATCGATCGATGCTAGCATGCATCGATCGATGCATGC 

Plate1A1_R2_AGCATCGATGCAGCATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCAGCTAGTCT
Plate1A1_R2_AGCATGCATCGATCGTAGCTAGCAGCGAGCGGCATCGATCGAT

Plate1A2_R1_CAGCTAGATGCATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATGCTAGCTTAC 
Plate1A2_R1_CAGTAGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATCGATGCTAGCTAGC 
Plate1A2_R1_ACAACGTAGCTAGCTAGCTACTACTAGTCATCATCGATGCTAG 
Plate1A2_R1_CAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGGCTACATCGATCGTAGCTAGTCGA 
Plate1A2_R1_CAGTCAGCATGCTATCGATCGTAGCTAGTCATCGATGTAGTGA

... etc.
```

This means I need to be able to grab the first 11 characters of each line, search for where that pattern no longer occurs in the line below, and insert a blank line at that point.

I've tried *sed* and *awk* efforts with `while read line` loops, but can't seem to find a way to hold the first 11 characters in a search variable to be used through the consecutive lines of a text file, if that search variable is 'stuck' in the processing of an individual line.

I'm hoping someone can help with a solution that would allow the referenced file to be accessed with a redirect (<) (with hundreds of lines of DNA sequence data in this format, and a couple of hundred distinct 'plate names' defined as the script moves through the file line-by-line), e.g.

```
while read line ; do echo "${line:0:11}" ; done < filename.txt
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If you do you care if a empty line at start: `awk 'substr($0,0,11)!=p{print ""}p=substr($0,0,11)'`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
  thisplate=substr($0, 1, 11); 
  if (thisplate != plate) { 
    print ""; 
    plate=thisplate 
  };
  print }' < input | sed '1d'
```

This is a longer version of Sukminder's comment that just came in; it saves the 11-charcter prefix and prints a newline if the new prefix differs from the previous prefix. The `sed` deletes the empty first line.

Comment: you could use `if (plate != "") {print ""};`and get rid of the `sed` command.